# Where do all these messages come from?

Tags: java, spring-integration, eai

This configuration works fine, but inbound-channel-adapter which is supposed to poll every 15 secs is running continously. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doning wrong?

```
<si:channel id="msgChannel" />

    <si:inbound-channel-adapter ref="jdbcInputAdapter"
        method="fetchData" channel="msgChannel">
        <si:poller>
            <si:interval-trigger interval="15000" />
        </si:poller>
    </si:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <si:outbound-channel-adapter ref="shouter"  method="shout" channel="msgChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A poller will by default pick up all the messages from the channel or source each poll. You can tweak this with the `max-messages-per-poll` attribute. If you set that to 1 you will see the behavior you expect.